# Children's book from the 1980s about boy/girl twins, mind-reading aliens (squid, maybe?), maybe set in Australia

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, young-adult

I read this book in late 1980s, maybe 1990s, in the UK.

I am certain it had twins, a boy and a girl, and the boy was communicating with or unwillingly having his mind read by aliens.

Things I may be misremembering:

- The aliens were giant squids.
- It was set in Australia.
- There's a scene set at night where the boy can sense these creatures nearby.
- The mind-reading requires them to be close to him.